# debian ntp client accesses wrong ntp server

Tags: debian, ntp

i have ntp.conf setup to only use us pool ntp servers and yet the system keeps trying to contact ntp servers outside of the us. i can't figure out what actions to take to stop non-us ntp server access. any help would be appreciated. debian wheezy up-to-date. The only changes to ntp.conf (that I am aware of) after ntp was installed where the changes to the four server lines. ntp has been restarted several times. system rebooted too.

ntp.conf:

```
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift


# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.
#statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable


# You do need to talk to an NTP server or two (or three).
#server ntp.your-provider.example

# pool.ntp.org maps to about 1000 low-stratum NTP servers.  Your server will
# pick a different set every time it starts up.  Please consider joining the
# pool: <http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html>
server 0.us.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.us.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.us.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.us.pool.ntp.org iburst

# Access control configuration; see /usr/share/doc/ntp-doc/html/accopt.html for
# details.  The web page <http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions>
# might also be helpful.
#
# Note that "restrict" applies to both servers and clients, so a configuration
# that might be intended to block requests from certain clients could also end
# up blocking replies from your own upstream servers.

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

# Clients from this (example!) subnet have unlimited access, but only if
# cryptographically authenticated.
#restrict 192.168.123.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrust


# If you want to provide time to your local subnet, change the next line.
# (Again, the address is an example only.)
#broadcast 192.168.123.255

# If you want to listen to time broadcasts on your local subnet, de-comment the
# next lines.  Please do this only if you trust everybody on the network!
#disable auth
#broadcastclient
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: What is your actual config? Did you restart ntpd after changing configuration?

Comment: Please, edit your question and add the content of '/etc/ntp.conf" file. Which changes have you done to config files?

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that servers in the `us.pool.ntp.org` domain are actually present in the United States. A server's presence in that domain simply indicates that it's "sufficiently close" (in network terms) to be able to serve time to that country.

If you don't like the servers you're getting from the Pool, either set up your own GPS based ones or use some of the US-based publicly available ones.

---

The first paragraph at http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone says,

> In most cases it's best to use pool.ntp.org to find an NTP server (or 0.pool.ntp.org, 1.pool.ntp.org, etc if you need multiple server names). The system will try finding the closest available servers for you.

You might like to try that instead of mandating a US zone. I would say that this is counter-intuitive, and I don't know if it will actually work for you, but it's probably worth considering.

When I added my (home) server to the pool I seem to recall I was asked which zones I wanted it added to, but I can't confirm that right now.

Comment: ok, i understand what you are saying but both human intuition and naming semantics leave the user, me, confused at best. and i will bet i am not the only one. i am regularly getting time servers from the middle-east. i would think they are NOT close geographically nor network-access-wise. however, I will take your advise and stop using the pool altogether and use specifically us located ones. thanks for the information.

Comment: @Jon a little more information added for you.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to choose the servers manually, e.g:

```
#tick.ucla.edu
server 164.67.62.194
#ntp.okstate.edu
server 139.78.97.128
#navobs1.gatech.edu
server 130.207.244.240
```

information that might be useful for you:

[How to join your linux server to the NTP pool project](https://ncomputers.org/ntp)

[NTP Server Online Tester](https://servertest.online/ntp)

Comment: Why not use the names instead of the IP addresses? This way recent versions of NTP will be able to track changes of IP address for those names.

Comment: @roaima agree :D